# How to emit an event in Jmeter?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In javascript:

```
socket.emit('ui:home:loaded',{_id: '576a5bde4dd0ec7a...'});
```

I'm trying using [WebSocket Sampler](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler)

- Request data : 2probe
- Response data : 3probe

[image]

But I can't emit an event.

How can do this in the Jmeter?

Comment: Can you show your websocket sampler configuration ?

Comment: My Websocket Sampler
: http://i.imgur.com/pvEt5I9.png

Comment: Duplicate question, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43473793/emit-an-event-to-socket-io-in-jmeter/71581375#71581375).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working for me.

[使用jmeter对websocket进行压力测试](http://www.cnblogs.com/towersxu/p/4568254.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try in the following WebsocketSAmpler setting in Request Data textarea:

> 'ui:home:loaded',{_id: '576a5bde4dd0ec7a...'}

Also is [this](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/cloud-based-jmeter-websocket-testing/) the approach you followed ?