# emit an event to socket io in jmeter

Tags: websocket, socket.io, jmeter, stress-testing

i'm trying to test socket.io in jmeter.

this is my socket sampler config:

[image]

i can get 3probe by sending 2probe but not able to emit an event .

note that i tried this way :

```
GET HTTP/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1417083573418-0
GET HTTP /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1417083577728-2&sid=vgBVmF_jpLhlexsQAAAB
GET WS /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=vgBVmF_jpLhlexsQAAAB
```

[image]

and this is my chrome ws frames :

[image]

but how can i emit event?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

This works,[rasa_socket_io.jmx](https://github.com/ourdaidai/test_rasa_socket_io/blob/5796abb896e4304dde8236aef7f6c3fdd16b91dc/rasa_socket_io.jmx)

Open it in **jmeter**. Check variables defined in **Test Plan**